# DegitError "could not parse"

Tags: node.js, git, templates, degit

We have a private Gitlab service and project templates on our Gitlab.

My workflow is that I create an empty projet on our Gitlab, then clone it on my computer and then I need to upload one of our template to begin the project.

I want to do the same as "create-react-app" with our own templates.

My problem is that since I try to clone on a non-empty folder, it's impossible.
So I tried to use "degit" but it doesn't work when I aim our private Gitlab.

I get this error :

```js
throw new DegitError(`could not parse ${src}`, {
```

Does anyone knows how to solve it ? Or atleast how to copy my template from our private Gitlab in any ways.

Thanks in advance !